# Brace expansion with variable?

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, variable-expansion

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo "Welcome"
done
```

Would work, displays Welcome 5 times.

```
#!/bin/sh
howmany=`grep -c $1 /root/file`
for i in {1..$howmany}
do
   echo "Welcome"
done
```

Doesn't work! `howmany` would equal 5 as that is what the output of `grep -c` would display. $1 is parameter 1 which is specific when running the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: add an echo $howmany for debugging to check it IS 5
'doesn't work' ==> could mean anything,  send the full output of a run.

Comment: You can use the seq command. For i in $(seq 1 $howmany)

Comment: @user2701753, I tried with: `x=5; for i in {1..$x}; do echo "Hi"; done` and also doesn't work. It only prints `Hi` once.

Comment: I done some of the suggested comments: 
http://i.imgur.com/xCza7Fv.png

You can see the output above in the picture.

Comment: Bash is not ksh:  `exp={0..9}; echo $exp; 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Comment: @tjm3772 unfortunately not, that's where I got the `seq` idea from but that doesn't work with alphabetic characters. I couldn't find a solution to my problem at that answer, unless I'm missing it.

Comment: @GillesQuénot not entirely sure what you're saying but if you're telling me to use brace expansion, you can't put variables in the expansion in bash. I would need to do `{$range}` or at the very least `{$rangeFrom..$rangeTo}` but bash doesn't support this.

Comment: Check my answer. My example is `ksh`. I know the limitations of `bash`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

create a sequence to control your loop

```
for i in $(seq 1 $howmany); do
echo "Welcome";
done
```

Comment: `seq` is not a POSIX-standardized tool. It's not guaranteed to be installed at all on a POSIX system, much less to behave in any specific way.

Answer (score 33):

#### *Workarounds* for not being able to use variables in a sequence brace expression:

- If the intent is merely to **iterate over numbers in a range** - as in the OP's case - the **best choice is *not* to use brace expansion**, but instead use bash's **C-style loop** - see [user000001's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19432881/45375).

  - If the specific numbers aren't important and you simply need to execute a loop body a specified number of times, [Cole Tierney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434167/45375) is an option.
- If use of brace expansion *is* desired nonetheless:

  - If you **do NOT need the numbers in the list to have a *prefix or postfix***, use the **`seq`** utility with an *unquoted* command substitution (*small caveat*: `seq` is NOT a POSIX utility, but it is widely available); e.g.

    - `echo $(seq 3)` -> `1 2 3`; start number `1` *implied*

      - `echo $(seq -f '%02.f' 3)` -> `01 02 03` - zero-padded
    - `echo $(seq 2 4)` -> `2 3 4`; explicit start and end numbers
    - `echo $(seq 1 2 5)` -> `1 3 5`; custom increment (the `2` in the *middle*)
  - If you **DO need the numbers in the list to have a *prefix or postfix***, you have several choices:

    - Use the `seq` utility with its `-f` option for providing a `printf`-style format string (as used above for zero-padding), or pure Bash workarounds based on `eval` (extra care needed!) or building an *array* in a loop, all of which are detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33491280/45375).
    - You could also consider implementing the functionality generically, such as by writing a custom shell function or a custom script with utilities such as `awk` or `perl`.

#### Example of safe use of `eval` with variables driving a sequence brace expression:

The variables are validated beforehand, to make sure they contain decimal integers.

```
from=1 to=3  # sample values

# Ensure that $from and $to are decimal numbers and abort, if they are not.
(( 10#$from + 10#$to || 1 )) 2>/dev/null || { echo "Need decimal integers" >&2; exit 1; }

eval echo "A{$from..$to}"  # -> 'A1 A2 A3'
```

### General overview of brace expansion

The **main purpose of brace expansion** is to **expand to a list of tokens** with each token having an **optional prefix and/or postfix**; brace expansions must be **unquoted** and come in **2 flavors**:

- a ***fixed series* (list) of comma-separated strings** - **variables *supported***

  - specifies and expands to a ***fixed* number of tokens** (2 or more); e.g.:
  - `echo A{b,c,d}` -> `Ab Ac Ad`, i.e., 3 tokens, as implied by the number of args.
  - `echo {/,$HOME/}Library` e.g., -> `/Library /User/jdoe/Library`
  - Variable references - and even globs - *are* supported, but note that they get expanded *after* brace expansion, in its *result*, in the course of normal evaluation.
- a ***sequence* expression (range) with `..`, *typically* numerical** - **variables *NOT supported***

  - expands to a ***variable* number of tokens**, driven by ***literal* start and end points** (for **historical reasons**, **use of variables is NOT supported** - see the comments on [user000001's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19432881/45375)):

    - [rare] **strings**: only *single English letters* allowed; e.g. `{a..c}`
    - **numbers**: *decimal integers only*; e.g., `{1..10}`, `{10..1}`, `{-1..2}`

      - example with prefix and postfix: `A{1..3}#` -> `A1# A2# A3#`
      - *broken* example with *variables*: `{$from..$to} # !! FAILS` - `$from` and `$to` are interpreted as *literals* and therefore not recognized as either a single letter or a decimal integer - *no* brace expansion is performed (see below).

        - by contrast, **using variables *does* work in `zsh` and `ksh`**.
    - **bash 4+** adds two features:

      - optional **increment step value**:

        - `echo A{1..5..2}` -> `A1 A3 A5` - numbers incremented by 2
      - ability to **zero-pad**:

        - `echo A{001..003}` -> `A001 A002 A003`
- An ***invalid* brace expression** is ***not* expanded** (treated like a regular unquoted string, with `{` and `}` treated as *literals*):

  - `echo {}` -> `'{}'` - invalid as a brace expr.: at least *2* `,`-separated tokens needed

    - <sup>This allows the use of unquoted `{}` with `find`, for instance.</sup>
  - `echo {1..$to}` -> `'{1..<value-of-$to>}'` - invalid as a brace expr. in `bash`: variables not supported; however, *valid* in `ksh` and `zsh`.
  - (`fish`, by contrast, expands *any* `{...}` sequence; similarly, `zsh` has option `BRACE_CCL` (OFF by default) for expanding *individual* characters inside `{..}`, which effectively causes expansion of *any nonempty* `{...}` sequence.)

Answer (score 25):

The brace expansion is evaluated before the variables are expanded. You need a c-style for loop instead:

```
for ((i=1;i<=howmany;i++))
do
   echo "Welcome"
done
```

Comment: Why is that? Wouldn't it make more sense to first expand the variables, then the bracket expression?

Comment: @Shahbaz Perhaps it would make sense. But this is how they designed the language.

Comment: @Shahbaz It might, but `bash` simply doesn't. Originally, brace expansion was designed for things like `a{b,c}d` to be expanded to `abd acd`; the `{1..10}` syntax was a later addition, but the order of expansion was already fixed. I suspect it wasn't considered worth the trouble to change that to allow for parameters inside the braces. For what it's worth, `zsh` *does* allow parameter expansions inside brace expansions.

Comment: @chepner: Good to know; I was puzzled at first that it _does_ work with  variables in the _string-token list_ form: `v1=a v2=b; echo {$v1,$v2}` -> `'a b'`. Bash _first_ turns that into token list `"$v1 $v2"` (brace expansion), and _then_ expands the variable references (parameter expansion), correct? Since this expansion order must be retained for backward compatibility, using variables in the _numeric-range_ form cannot work, because, without knowing what numbers the variable references represent, bash cannot create the token list, because it doesn't know what and how many tokens to create.

Comment: @chepner:  Also good to know that you _can_ use variable references in `zsh`; ditto in `ksh`.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the "brace expansion" is performed before the "variable expansion"

```
for i in $(seq 1 $howmany)
```

works as @damienfrancois said, or, if you would like:

```
for i in $(eval echo "{$start..10}")
```

probably does, but don't use it for everyone's sanity.

Comment: You need "s not 's in the eval.   `for i in $(eval echo "{$start..10}")`

Answer (score 9):

You could also use a while loop:

```
while ((howmany--)); do
   echo "Welcome"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `eval` in this case:

```
howmany=`grep -c $1 /root/file`
for i in $(eval echo {1..$howmany}); do
    echo "Welcome"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

##### With `ksh`, can be run in a subshell in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=0-9

read -ra digits < <(
    ksh -c '
        range={$1}
        echo ${range/-/..}
    ' ksh $x
)
echo "${digits[@]}"
```

Will work with any brace expansion too.

##### With a filtered `eval` (use at your own risks, the first solution is preferred if `ksh` can be installed, and the filter have to be modified for other expansion than *digits*)

```
#!/bin/bash

x=1-3
case $x in
    '' | *[!0123456789-]*)
        printf '%s\n' "$0: $x: invalid entry" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
exp={$x}
eval "echo ${exp/-/..}"
```

If you try to make some code injection, like

```
x='$(reboot)'
```

you will have

```
script.sh: $(reboot): invalid entry
```

##### Output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: A shame if there isn't a way to do this without running a subshell but this is a great alternative, thank you!

Comment: Another alternative like other linked answer is to use `eval`, but I don't need it here

Comment: would you be able to explain how to accomplish this using `eval`? This `ksh` solution obviously has the downside that it will not work if `ksh` is not installed

Comment: `eval` is a serious can of worms -- unless you're very careful to escape everything else in the data being `eval`d (or, as the answer here does, _have nothing else at all_ in the variable you're `eval`ing) you can easily get security vulnerabilities that way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and Joe Herbert: check my answer. Looks safe, no?

Comment: @GillesQuénot `eval` works perfectly and definitely solves the problem. I think Charles still has a point about the security vulnerabilities though, as in order to make the solution work with letters you need to allow letters to be part of the input, which does reduce the security factor. Either way, for a local solution where I'm the only person who will run it, this works great, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Change the test for alphabetic characters if needed

Comment: Disclaimer applies not only for you, but for following persons coming in this thread.