# Use numeric value of input argument in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

I would like to use the numeric value of the input argument that I pass to a bash script like this:

`./script_pb3.sh out.txt 3`

Here I would like to take the second argument that I pass (i.e. the value 3) and use it as a numeric value inside my script, that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM=$2

for i in {1..$NUM}; do
        echo $i
done
```

But when I run it all I get is

```
{1..3}
```

Instead of

```
1
2
3
```

Can you please provide an explanation for why this is happening and a workaround? I think that this question aims at casting a string value to an integer value but I am not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432753/brace-expansion-with-variable) contains a debate concerning the answer to my issue (i.e. it assumes the answer is already known), but it does not come as an answer to my question, therefore I didn't find it in my first searches. Thank you, though, for pointing it out.

Comment: Use: `for ((i=1; i<=NUM; i++)); do
        echo $i;
done`

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use **seq**

```
for i in `seq 1 10`;
 do
    echo $i
 done
```

Reference: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

So, what you're looking for is : **seq 1 $2**

Comment: This is a legit answer as well. Please edit the seq into `seq 1 $2` so I can accept your answer to my question

Comment: The page you linked to contains numerous questionable, unnecessary, and/or obsolete suggestions. In this case, `seq` is an unnecessary (and nonstandard) external requirement when `bash` itself already has a more efficient C-style loop.

Comment: I was just trying to give an answer which I felt was closest to the problem in hand. If you felt otherwise, please feel free to post an answer which you feel would be better