# how to use variables with brace expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, brace-expansion

I have four files:

```
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt
```

in linux shell, I could use :
`ls {1..4}.txt`  to list all the four files
but if I set two variables : var1=1 and var2=4, how to list the four files?
that is:

```
var1=1
var2=4
ls {$var1..$var2}.txt  # error
```

what is the correct code?

Comment: A note regarding this question's original title, which referenced globbing: The mechanism used here is called [_brace expansion_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion); while it is often _combined_ with globbing, it's an independent mechanism for generating arbitrary strings.

Comment: In hindsight: this question is _almost_ a duplicate of [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19432753/45375); the added dimension here is the desire to use a _suffix_ (`.txt`) in the expansion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using *variables* with the *sequence-expression form* (`{<numFrom>..<numTo>}`) of [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion)** only works in `ksh` and `zsh`, but, unfortunately, **not in `bash`** (and  (mostly) strictly POSIX-features-only shells such as `dash` do not support brace expansion *at all*, so brace expansion should be avoided with `/bin/sh` altogether).

Given your symptoms, I assume you're using `bash`, **where you can only use *literals* in sequence expressions** (e.g., `{1..3}`); from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) (emphasis mine):

> Brace expansion is *performed before any other expansions*, and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result.

In other words: **at the time a brace expression is evaluated, variable references have not been expanded (resolved) yet**; interpreting *literals* such as `$var1` and `$var2` as numbers in the context of a sequence expression therefore fails, so the *brace expression is considered invalid and as not expanded*.
Note, however, that the variable references *are* expanded, namely at a later stage of overall expansion; in the case at hand the literal result is the single word `'{1..4}'` - an unexpanded brace expression with variable values expanded.

<sup>While the *list* form of brace expansion (e.g., `{foo,bar)`) is expanded the same way, later variable expansion is not an issue there, because no interpretation of the list elements is needed up front; e.g. `{$var1,$var2}` correctly results in the 2 words `1` and `4`.

As for *why* variables cannot be used in sequence expressions: historically, the *list* form of brace expansion came first, and when the sequence-expression form was later introduced, the order of expansions was already fixed.

For a general overview of brace expansion, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021862/45375).</sup>

---

#### Workarounds

Note: The workarounds focus on *numerical* sequence expressions, as in the question; the `eval`-based workaround also demonstrates use of variables with the less common *character* sequence expressions, which produce ranges of English *letters* (e.g., `{a..c}` to produce `a b c`).

---

A **`seq`-based workaround** is possible, [as demonstrated in Jameson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33491287/45375).

<sup>A small caveat is that `seq` is not a POSIX utility, but most modern Unix-like platforms have it.</sup>

To refine it a little, using `seq`'s `-f` option to supply a `printf`-style format string, and demonstrating two-digit zero-padding:

```
seq -f '%02.f.txt' $var1 $var2 | xargs ls # '%02.f'==zero-pad to 2 digits, no decimal places
```

Note that to make it fully robust - in case the resulting words contain spaces or tabs - you'd need to employ *embedded quoting*:

```
seq -f '"%02.f a.txt"' $var1 $var2 | xargs ls
```

`ls` then sees `01 a.txt`, `02 a.txt`, ... with the argument boundaries correctly preserved.

If you want to robustly collect the resulting words in a Bash *array* first, e.g., `${words[@]}`:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra words < <(seq -f '%02.f.txt' $var1 $var2)
ls "${words[@]}"
```

---

The following are **pure Bash workarounds:**

A ***limited* workaround** using Bash features only is to **use `eval`**:

```
var1=1 var2=4
# Safety check
(( 10#$var1 + 10#$var2 || 1 )) 2>/dev/null || { echo "Need decimal integers." >&2; exit 1; }
ls $(eval printf '%s\ ' "{$var1..$var2}.txt") # -> ls 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt
```

You can apply a similar technique to a ***character* sequence expression**;

```
var1=a var2=c
# Safety check
[[ $var1 == [a-zA-Z] && $var2 == [a-zA-Z] ]] || { echo "Need single letters."; exit 1; }
ls $(eval printf '%s\ ' "{$var1..$var2}.txt") # -> ls a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Note:

- A check is performed up front to ensure that `$var1` and `$var2` contain decimal integers or single English letters, which then makes it safe to use `eval`. *Generally, using `eval` with unchecked input is a security risk and use of `eval` is therefore best avoided*.
- Given that output from `eval` *must* be passed *unquoted* to `ls` here, so that the shell splits the output into individual arguments through words-splitting, this only works if the resulting filenames contain no embedded spaces or other shell metacharacters.

---

A **more robust, but more cumbersome pure Bash workaround** to **use an array** to create the equivalent words:

```
var1=1 var2=4

# Emulate brace sequence expression using an array.
args=()
for (( i = var1; i <= var2; i++ )); do
  args+=( "$i.txt" )
done

ls "${args[@]}"
```

- This approach bears no security risk and also works with resulting filenames with embedded shell metacharacters, such as spaces.
- Custom increments can be implemented by replacing `i++` with, e.g., `i+=2` to step in increments of 2.
- Implementing *zero-padding* would require use of `printf`; e.g., as follows:
  `args+=( "$(printf '%02d.txt' "$i")" )  # -> '01.txt', '02.txt', ...`

Answer (score 2):

For that particular piece of syntax (a "sequence expression") you're out of luck, see [Bash man page](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y  are
>          either  integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment,
>          is an integer.

However, you could instead use the `seq` utility, which would have a similar effect -- and the approach would allow for the use of variables:

```
var1=1
var2=4
for i in `seq $var1 $var2`; do
    ls ${i}.txt
done
```

Or, if calling `ls` four times instead of once bothers you, and/or you want it all on one line, something like:

```
for i in `seq $var1 $var2`; do echo ${i}.txt; done | xargs ls
```

From [seq(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) man page:

> ```
>    seq [OPTION]... LAST
>    seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
>    seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
> ```