# How do I use For...In f{a,b,c,d}c, but with variables?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, terminal, for-in-loop

I'm trying to make a loop in Bash. I tested the loop with `for adr in a{a,b,c}d` and it works perfectly with `aad, abd, acd`

But if I have a variable with the value `a{a,b,c}d`, it doesn't return the above values; instead it runs only once with the value `a{a,b,c}d`.
How do I enable this?

Alternatively, I'm trying to take an input from the user, and then replace all instances of `~const~` with `{b,c,d,f,g...y,z}` and then run the loop I described above.

Unfortunately, as I said, it isn't working. Is there any oher way to make this work?

Comment: See: [how to use variables with brace expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33491233/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

This code is a roundabout way of doing what you want. It outputs everything on a new line:

```
test=( a b c ) #declare the array
for index in "${test[@]}"; do #uses for loop to go through each item in the array
echo "{a{$index}d}" | tr -d '{}'; #echoes the result without curly braces
done
```

Hope this was what you were looking for!

Comment: It's almost what I want. Only difference, the 'a' and the 'd' are also meant to be variables that the user enters. In fact, the user will input a~const~d, and I want to display abd, acd, add, afd ...

Comment: You dont need to echo `{ }` and then remove them with `tr`. Just don't echo those brackets at all: `echo "a${index}d"` or in case of variables `echo "${start}${index}${end}"` where `start="a"` and `end="d"`

Comment: I know this is somewhat older, but you could edit my answer.. Instead of "test=( a b c )", you could have "test=( $a $b $c )."

Answer (score 0):

These are some workarounds:

```
$ aa=( a{a,b,c}d );for adr in ${aa[@]};do echo "$adr";done #using array
aad
abd
acd

$ aa=$(echo a{a,b,c}d);for adr in ${aa};do echo "$adr";done #without array
aad
abd
acd
```

This is how above can work with variables:

```
$ start="a"
$ var1="a"
$ var2="b"
$ var3="c"
$ end="d"
$ aa=$(echo $start{${var1},${var2},${var3}}$end)
$ for adr in $aa;do echo "$adr";done 
aad
abd
acd
```

Comment: You're right, I accidentally added an additional loop. Removing now.

Comment: I tried both of what you suggested. They work perfectly in the terminal, but when I try to implement in the code, the value of $adr comes out to a{b,c,d}d, even within the loop. Is this because I'm taking the value of $aa as an input?

Comment: @15KanurajBeri See update in my answer on how you can make this work with variables.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. But, if the user just enters "abc~const~", with no ending variable, then how will we split it?

Comment: @15KanurajBeri If you unset (or not set at all) the last variable `$end` in my example , will work as expected. Splitting input text to three texts and apply brace expansion in the middle text, is a whole new exercise. Moreover you can take a look to parameter expansion  `${parameter:+word}`  (see man bash for details - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)