# Bash wildcard pattern using `seq`

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying the following command:

```
ls myfile.h1.{`seq -s ',' 3501 3511`}*
```

But `ls` raises the error:

```
ls: cannot access myfile.h1.{3501,3502,3503,3504,3505,3506,3507,3508,3509,3510,3511}*: No such file or directory
```

Seems like `ls` is thinking the entire line is a filename and not a wildcard pattern. But if I just copy that command `ls myfile.h1.{3501,3502,3503,3504,3505,3506,3507,3508,3509,3510,3511}*` in the terminal I get the listing as expected.

Why does typing out the command in full work, but not the usage with `seq`?

Comment: Does `ls myfile.h1.{$(seq -s ',' 3501 3511)}*` work?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sadly no..... The error raised is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`seq` is not needed for your case, try

```
$ ls myfile.h1.{3500..3511}
```

if you want to use `seq` I would suggest using format option

```
$ ls $(seq -f 'myfile.h1.%g' 3501 3511)
```

but I don't think there is any reason to do so.

**UPDATE:**
Note that I didn't notice the globbing in the original post.  With that, the brace extension still preferred way

```
$ ls myfile.h1.{3500..3511}*
```

perhaps even factoring the common digit out, if your bash support zero padding

```
$ ls myfile.h1.35{00..11}*
```

if not you can extract at least 3 out

```
$ ls myfile.h1.3{500..511}*
```

Note that the `seq` alternative won't work with globbing.

Other answer has more details...

Comment: OMG! Can't believe it was that simple! But, as a follow up query, any idea why seq did not work?

Comment: Probably because both the `$(seq)` and the `{3501,3502}` are bash expansions. So bash expanded the `$(seq)` but then had done its expansion and didn't expand `{3501,3502}` any more.

Comment: @chw21: Indeed; to state it explicitly: brace expansion is the _first_ type of expansion that Bash applies, _before_ parameter (variable) expansion and command substitution (`\`...\`` or `$(...)`), which - unfortunately - means that only _literal_ sequence brace expansions are supported in Bash.

Comment: Nicely done; a caveat regarding the `seq`-based alternative, given that globbing is involved: it only works with format strings that do not have embedded whitespace; e.g., while `ls 'my file.'{3500..3511}*` would work, 
`ls $(seq -f 'my file.%g*' 3500 3511)` would not.

Answer (score 4):

**[karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35592998/45375), which uses a *literal* sequence brace expansion expression, is the right solution.**

As for **why your approach didn't work**:

**Bash's [*brace expansion* `{...}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) only works with *literal* expressions** - neither variable references nor, as in your case, command substitutions (`` `...` ``, or, preferably, `$(...)`) work<sup>[1]</sup> - for a concise overview, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021862/45375) of mine.

With careful use of `eval`, however, you *can* work around this limitation; to wit:

```
from=3501 to=3511
# CAVEAT: Only do this if you TRUST that $from and $to contain 
#         decimal numbers only.
eval ls "myfile.h1.{$from..$to}*"
```

[@ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti) suggests the following improvement in a comment to make the use of `eval` safe here:

```
# Use parameter expansion to remove all non-digit characters from the values 
# of $from and $to, thus ensuring that they either contain only a decimal
# number or the empty string; this expansion happens *before* eval is invoked.
eval ls "myfile.h1.{${from//[^0-9]/}..${to//[^0-9]/}}*"
```

As for **how your command was actually evaluated**:

<sup>Note: Bash applies [7-8 kinds of expansions to a command line](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html); only the ones that actually come into play here are discussed below.</sup>

- first, the command in command substitution `` `seq -s ',' 3501 3511` `` is executed, and replaced by its output (also note the trailing `,`):

  - `3501,3502,3503,3504,3505,3506,3507,3508,3509,3510,3511,`
- the result then forms a single word with its prefix, `myfile.h1.{` and its suffix, `}*`, yielding:

  - `myfile.h1.{3501,3502,3503,3504,3505,3506,3507,3508,3509,3510,3511,}*`
- pathname expansion (globbing) is then applied to the result - in your case, since no files match, it is left *as-is* (by default; shell options `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob` could change that).
- finally, *literal* `myfile.h1.{3501,3502,3503,3504,3505,3506,3507,3508,3509,3510,3511,}*` is passed to `ls`, which - because it doesn't refer to an existing filesystem item - results in the error message you saw.

---

<sup>[1] Note that the limitation only applies to *sequence* brace expansions (e.g., `{1..3}`); *list* brace expansions (e.g, `{1,2,3}`) are not affected, because no up-front interpretation (interpolation) is needed; e.g. `{$HOME,$USER}` works, because brace expansion results expanding the list to separate words `$HOME`, and `$USER`, which are only *later* expanded.

Historically, *sequence* brace expansions were introduced later, at a time when the order of shell expansions was already fixed.</sup>

Comment: Is it worthwhile to mention `eval` as a strategy for placing command substitution inside brace expansion? `eval ls "myfile.{$(seq -s, 3501 3511)}"` (though of course I agree that in this particular case, `seq` is redundant). In very limited quantities, especially where outside data are carefully sanitized or not used at all, I would submit that eval is not so evil.

Comment: Thanks, @ghoti; the other answer of mine that I link to already contains an `eval`-based example, but I've now added one to this answer as well.

Comment: Looks good. For extra safety, you could even sanitize in-place: `eval ls "myfile.h1.{${from//[^0-9]/}..${to//[^0-9]/}*"`, since parameter expansion happens before the command is evaluated by `eval`. It's not the prettiest, but we should be kind to the paranoid people nonetheless.

Comment: @ghoti: Thanks - that's a nifty, pragmatic approach; I've added it to the answer.