# Iterating throught bash script arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to create a bash script which can be executed as follows:

```
bash myscript.sh -n n -k k -p1 p1 -p2 p2
```

where `n,k,p1,p2` are some parameters and `-n, -k, -p1, -p2` indicate which parameters are specified. I would like to be able to parse them. The obvious solution would be to use `getopt`, which doesn't work since there are options with name consisting of more than one character. Iterating tthrought the `$@` variable like this:

```
for op in $@ ...
```

is no good either, since I cannot access a neighbor. Is there a way to iterate through the list 'normally', something like this?

```
for i in {1..$@}; do
    case ${$i} in
        -n) # do something, accessing ${i+1}
         ...
    esac
done
```

Comment: BTW, this is covered in BashFAQ #35: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shift` to remove options after you've processed them.

```
while (($# > 0)); do
    case $1 in
        -n)  use $2; shift 2;;
        -k)  use $2; shift 2;;
        -p1) use $2; shift 2;;
        -p2) use $2; shift 2;;

        *) echo "Unrecognized option $1" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: And maybe add devfault values in case these are not always required to be set via commandline ...

Answer (score 2):

**[John Kugelman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632383/45375) is the way to go**, but just to show how it could be done with **array-index-based access to `$@`**, the (pseudo) array of input arguments, involving shell arithmetic:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= $#; i+=2 )); do
    this=${!i} # get argument with (1-based) index i; same as: ${@:i:1} 
    next=${@:i+1:1}  # get argument i + 1
    case $this in
        -n) echo "$this value: [$next]";;
        -k) echo "$this value: [$next]";;
        -p1) echo "$this value: [$next]";;
        -p2) echo "$this value: [$next]";;
        *) echo "Unrecognized option: $this" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

Note that this snippet makes the following assumptions, which makes it unsuitable for most real-world uses:

- Your script supports only options, not operands (non-option arguments).
- All options require an option-argument, and it must be separated from the option by whitespace.

---

As for **what you've tried:**

By `{1..$@}` you probably meant `{1..$#}` in order to enumerate all indices (`$#` is the *count* of input arguments), which, however, doesn't work either, because [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) only works with *literal* values, unfortunately.  <sup>There are workarounds, but [they're not pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021862/45375).</sup>

Note that the usual way of obtaining the list of indices from a Bash array does *not* work with pseudo-array `$@`:

- `${!@}` yields the empty string
- whereas copying `$@` to a true array first *does* work: `args=( "$@" ); echo "${!args[@]}"`

The best solution in this case is to use the C-style `for` loop demonstrated above.

`${$i}` in an attempt to access the `i`-th argument is syntactically invalid in Bash; what *does* work, however, is to use [variable indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection):<sup>Thanks, [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici)</sup>
With `$i` equaling `2`, `${!i}` is equivalent to `$2`, for instance.

This syntax, however, doesn't work with *calculated* indices (unless you awkwardly define additional variables such as `iPlus1=$(( i + 1 ))` and then use `${!iPlus1}`).

Fortunately, however, when it comes to index-based element access, `$@` *does* behave like regular Bash arrays (except that the first element has index `1`, not `0`):

- Thus, `${!i}` is equivalent to `${@:i:1}`, which returns the (`1`) element with index `$i` - note how I've used *no* `$` prefix when referring to `$i` in the index spec., because it is evaluated in an [*arithmetic* context](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr), where `$`-prefixing variable references is optional and simple integer calculations can be performed.
- This enables element access based on *calculating* the index: the element with index `$i + 1` can be accessed with `${@:i+1:1}`.

Comment: In bash, you can use `${!i}`