# Assign variable inside for loop

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to do a simple for{} loop and I encountered problem with assign a variable inside loop. I will try to explain it on example:

```
DIFF=(`date +%s -d 20120203`-`date +%s -d 20120126`)/86400   # Difference between 2 dates.
echo $DIFF
end_date_change='20120126'

for i in {1..$DIFF}   #Difference between 2 dates inside loop
do
end_date_change=$(end_date_change -d "-1 day")  # Now, after every loop I would like to decrease date
echo $end_date_change
done
```

So the output should looks:

```
20120126
20120127
20120128
20120201
20120202
20120203
```

Anyone? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [\[ shellcheck \]](http://shellcheck.net) which will give you a handful of suggestions regarding this script.

Comment: inside the loop after the do... end_date_change=$(date -d "$end_date_change - 1 day")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19432753/2088135 addresses one of your issues (using a variable inside a brace expansion)

Comment: Thanks it helps me, one more question: output of date is : eg. Fri Jun 5 00:00:00 UTC 2015 , where and how to convert it into eg. 2015-06-05 ?

Comment: For the last question, `date`'s manual holds the answer.