# loop wth floating value increment in shell

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to execute a script within the following loop.

```
x=10.000; nx=3; dx=0.125; y=15.000; ny=5; dy=0.120
for i in {1..3};do
for j in {1..5};do
xi=xi+($i-1)*dx
yj=yj+($j-1)*dy
echo $xi $yj #run the script which needs the values of xi and yj for each run
done
done
```

desire output

```
10.000 15.000
10.000 15.120
10.000 15.240
10.000 15.360
10.000 15.480
10.125 15.000
10.125 15.120
10.125 15.240
10.125 15.360
10.125 15.480
10.250 15.000
10.250 15.120
10.250 15.240
10.250 15.360
10.250 15.480
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=10.000; nx=3; dx=0.125; y=15.000; ny=5; dy=0.120
for i in {1..3};do
    for j in {1..5};do
        xi=$( echo "$x+($i-1)*$dx" | bc )
        yj=$( echo "$y+($j-1)*$dy" | bc )
        echo $xi $yj
    done
done
```

You can use `bc` for floating-point arithmetic. Your equation had an issue too, it should be `x` and `y` instead of `xi` and `yj`

Also, I think you wish to use `nx` and `ny`, see [Brace expansion with variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432753/brace-expansion-with-variable)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was looking for this only. Many thanks. As I need to pass the x and y values for each execution of my script.

Answer (score 2):

In `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk -v outer_start="10.000" -v outer_loop_times="3" -v outer_diff="0.125" -v inner_start="15.000" -v inner_loop_times="5" -v inner_diff="0.120" '
BEGIN{
    for(i=1;i<=outer_loop_times;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=inner_loop_times;j++){
            print outer_start,inner_start
            inner_start=sprintf("%.03f",inner_start+inner_diff)
        }
        outer_start=sprintf("%.03f",outer_start+outer_diff)
    }
}'
```

Comment: I expect that would run orders of magnitude faster than the equivalent shell script.