# Looping through a sequence

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a ping sweep using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in seq 74 254
do
  ping -w 4 192.168.1.$x
done
```

According to what I've read on the Internet this should be looping from 74 **to** 254 but
outputs only results from 74 **and** 254.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to surround the `seq` call with a "dollar parenthesis" set.

```
for x in $(seq 74 254)
do
  ping -w 4 192.168.1.$x
done
```

If you don't do that, `seq 74 254` will be parsed a list of values. This is called **command substitution**. According to the manual page of **`bash`**:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.
> Bash performs the expansion by executing [the] command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command.

Note: Charles Duffy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64577873/4375327) is better.

Comment: Interestingly, those backticks worked too.

Comment: However, this isn't particularly good practice either. `seq` isn't built into bash, and neither is it POSIX-stardardized; it isn't guaranteed to exist or work at all, much less work in any particular way.

Comment: @road_runner, backticks are legacy pre-POSIX syntax -- when you have a 1970s-era shell they're the only way to do command substitution, but `$(...)` is, as of 1992 (and thus today), the standard -- and it has significant advantages (easier to nest, doesn't change how backslashes behave inside it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  OK, gotcha, it's best to go for `$(...)` and leave backticks to history.

Comment: Yup. See [Have backticks in sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) for a longer discussion, likewise [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is a [C-style `for` loop](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for):

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( x=74; x<=254; x++)); do
  ping -w 4 "192.168.1.$x"
done
```

Comment: or use bash-ism: ```for x in {74..254}```

Comment: @vgersh99, you should add your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Amessihel after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432753/brace-expansion-with-variable), I'd rather leave it as a comment - thanks.

Comment: @vgersh99, ...the other thing about that bashism is that it eats all the memory to generate a list before it actually runs any of the items in the list. The C-style `for` loop suggested in this answer doesn't precalculate the numbers -- it generates them only as they're needed. Hardly matters for this short little list, but it could make a difference for a big one.