# How to use variables in brace expansion

Tags: linux, bash

This works as expected:

```
$ echo file-{00..03}
file-00 file-01 file-02 file-03
```

This does not do what I wanted:

```
$ start=00
$ end=03
$ echo file-{$start..$end}
file-{00..03}
```

The reason is that brace expansion is performed before any other epansion.

In my case, the sequence limits are in the variables `start` and `end`.

Any clever way to hack my way around this?

Comment: You have the sequence limits in the variables already, do you care to use `for` loop instead of brace expansion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brace expansion with variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432753/brace-expansion-with-variable)

Comment: @rustyhu No for loop, I need to make use of `xargs` to process the `echo` output (to avoid invoking thousands of processes)

Comment: Bash does not provide for use of variables within brace expansion. There are hacks that you can use to make it work -- but when you find yourself doing so, it should tell you to refactor your script instead.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin major refactoring is out of the question. I need to hack my way around in this particular statement - the cleaner, the better

Comment: @rustyhu yepp, that answer provides a couple of options, including my eval. Thanks!

Comment: It's doable with `eval` as you know. Howerver make sure whatever you generate isn't used with `rm` or other commands if the expression inadvertently expands to `/` (or the like)

Answer (score 1):

I have this:

```
$ eval echo file-{$start..$end}
file-00 file-01 file-02 file-03
```

But I am open to less ugly suggestions.

Comment: `eval` is one letter away from `"evil"`. Use sparingly, if at all.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yepp, that's what I meant by "less ugly"