# bash loop problem - output not as expected (returned command)

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, brace-expansion

I have a script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..$1}
do
    echo $i
done
```

someone could explain me why if I try
./script.sh 10 my output is {1..10}?
expected
1
2
...
10

Comment: See: [Brace expansion with variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19432753/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing the parameter that you're passing in instead of printing out the loop iteration. Try:

`echo $i`

Comment: my mistake, it was $i not $1 but output is wrong